# Segmentation Fault on Android when using OpenGL ES 3 functions

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to create an application using the NDK. I'm using ndk-build because I'm also using some external libraries which don't yet support CMake. This is the relevant line in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lEGL -lGLESv3
```

Everything builds (compiles and links) just fine, but when I try to use a function from OpenGL ES 3.0+ (like `glGenVertexArrays`), I get a segmentation fault.

When I look into the debugger, though, I see this:

[image]

So, it is linking against `libGLESv1_CM.so` for reasons I don't understand.

Also, on my header files, I have `#include <GLES3/gl3.h>` and my device supports OpenGL ES 3.2 (I also saw the `libGLESv3.so` file on `/system/lib/`).

What could I be missing?

Comment: glBindBuffer is defined by ES 1.1. I wouldn´t worry about that.

Comment: segfaults in runtime from opengl is usually because of bad pointers. you sure you sending good pointers in glGenVertexArrays, i.e. an adress to pre-allocated memory size of n*GLuint?

Comment: Completely sure. But also, you can see that the function pointer is set to NULL.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. What do the proc address functions return? https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglGetProcAddress.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

The external library I was using included the source [`gl3stub.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/android/ndk_helper/gl3stub.c), presumably for supporting older OpenGL ES specifications. This was nullifying the pointers to newer APIs. Removing this source and recompiling the external library solved the issue.